# AWS Lambda using lightFM package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function using python and lightFM to get product recommendations. It is structured as follows:

- Load the lightFM model using pickle
- Receive the parameters via AWS API Gateway
- Performs inference on the received parameters
- Return the most likely products to that specific user

The problem is that when it calls the method "predict" from the LightFM class, it exits the process with the following error on AWS CloudWatch, with no stack trace:

```
REPORT RequestId: 31be3ec0-b04a-11e8-9805-e5d84a21cf93  Duration: 180.45 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 162 MB   
RequestId: 31be3ec0-b04a-11e8-9805-e5d84a21cf93 Process exited before completing request
```

To make it worse, sometimes the Lambda function works perfectly.

It is possible to force this error one time by sending a lot of requests to the Lambda function consecutively in an asynchronous way (if all the calls are synchronous, there is no error).

And after the first time it gives an error, it stops working until I upload the Lambda function again and make some changes on the memory configuration of the Lambda function.

Does anyone know if there is a problem with cython and pickle, or something like that?  Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The line,

> Process exited before completing request

indicates there is no events in loop to process by the lambda engine.
Your code is not making a callback or somewhere callback is missed in the callback chain.

In this case if you are using lightFM package and waiting on a callback from the package, it never get called and nothing  to process in the event chain.

The way to usually to fix this to use promise and wait for certain time and handle the timeout and call the context.done or callback to complete the function.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find what was terminating the lambda before it actually ends, but I found a workaround. I created my own "predict" method using the user and item representations from the model.